# Making a combination of non-primitive properties unique in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Does anyone know how to use another class as a part of a multiple-column unique index using Entity Framework's Code First approach?

I wish to make the combination of the ExternalId and the PersonCategory.Id for all Persons unique, so that there can exist only one Person in the database for the same pair of "ExternalId" and "PersonCategory.Id". Any ideas on how to achieve this behavior?

I tried using the Index annotation, but this resulted in making only the ExternalId unique, the Category property was ignored.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_Person_PersonCategory", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_Person_PersonCategory", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public PersonCategory Category { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class PersonCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a unique index (which lives in the DB) to a navigation property (which is an EF element). The index will have to be in the actual foreign key used to link Person and PersonCategory.

In order to configure that, you'll have explicitly define the PersonCategoryId in the Person entity.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Index("IX_Person_PersonCategory", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string ExternalId { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Person_PersonCategory", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public PersonCategory Category { get; set; }

    ...
}
```